# How to remove a class on all the other elements except on the element that was clicked

Tags: javascript, events, classname

Hello I want to remove a class on all the other elements except on the clicked element.

my code is looking like this so far but i can not find a solution

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".element");

function toggleOpen() {
    this.classList.toggle('open');
    elemets.forEach(ele => {
        ele.classList.remove('open'); // buts this removes the class from all 
       the elements I am looking for something that removes the class on just 
       the other one element containing the class except on the clicked one.
    }) 
}

elements.forEach(ele => ele.addEventListener('click', toggleOpen));
```

Comment: element.classList.add("open"); after for each

Comment: `this.classList.add("open");` after the forEach loop. There's also a typo: `elemets`

Answer (score 2):

You were really close, just use an `if` clause in your forEach loop to skip the element you clicked by comparing with `this`, also, you had a typo in the function:

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.element');

function toggleOpen() {
    this.classList.toggle('open');
    elements.forEach(ele => {
        if (ele !== this) ele.classList.remove('open');
    });
}

elements.forEach(ele => ele.addEventListener('click', toggleOpen));
```

```css
.element { color: red; }
.open { color: green; }
```

```html
<button class="element">1</button>
<button class="element">2</button>
<button class="element">3</button>
<button class="element">4</button>
```

Comment: This is the best answer, Thank you

Comment: Glad to help! :)